# Inserting hypertext into database

Tags: sql, insert, cpu-word

Hello I am trying to insert a hypertext into database table.First I seperated all words make them small letters and list on listbox1 which works right.

And here is my table word;

```
id(int),word(nvarchar),sid(int),frequency(int),weight(float),f(boolean) by order

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int id=0;
            ListBox1.Items.Clear();
            string strNew = Request.Form["TextBox1"];
           // File.WriteAllText(@"\Users\'uykusuz\Documents\text.txt", strNew);
            int n = strNew.Split(' ').Length;

            strNew=strNew.ToLower();

            var results = strNew.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Length > 1)
                                          .GroupBy(x => x)
                                          .Select(x => new { Count = x.Count(), Word = x.Key })
                                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);

            foreach (var item in results)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} occured {1} times", item.Word, item.Count));

            foreach (var item in results) {//here trying to insert word its id and some other informations but for now they can stay null(yes,null allowed for them)
                id++;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into word values('" + id + "','" + item.Word.Text + "','0'),'0'),'0'),'0')", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

            }

        }
```

I always get this error when I hit the button;

> ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The
>   connection's current state is closed.

EDIT1:

```
foreach (var item in results) {
                con.Open();
                id++;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into word values('" + id + "','" + item.Word + "','0','0','0','0')", con); 
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

            }
```

I have changed like this but Now I am getting this error

The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

Comment: con.Open() before cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ... you said which connection your query will use, but you didn't opened it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your last lines of code to my example. You closed your connection to database every time when you iterates your results collection.

```
using (conn){
    conn.Open();

    foreach (var item in results) {//here trying to insert word its id and some other informations but for now they can stay null(yes,null allowed for them)
        id++;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into word values('" + id + "','" + item.Word.Text + "','0'),'0'),'0'),'0')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the connection after the

```
  using (con){
        con.Open();

        foreach (var item in results) {//here trying to insert word its id and some other informations but for now they can stay null(yes,null allowed for them)
            id++;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into word values('" + id + "','" + item.Word.Text + "','0'),'0'),'0'),'0')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
con.close();
```